# Auto Layout on three UIButtons having same width and height with in a scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

Image is attached to give a clear idea what i'm doing.
[image]

Sorry I hadn't given the full information I want these three buttons to remain on the bottom in all the screens(iPhone 6 and 6+)

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Okay, I see. Add Top/Bottom/Leading and Horizontal Space constraints for these buttons.

Comment: plz see the edited description. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution should be the following:

- **Left** button. Add *Bottom* and *Leading* constraint to **Superview**.
- **Middle** button. Add *Center Y* and *Horizontal* space to **left** button.
- **Right button**. Add *Center Y* and *Horizontal* space to **Middle** button.

That's it.

Comment: orkenstein Thanks